# The problem is getting the correct information from the templates in selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing an issue with selecting templates and get data categories and products in my interface. When I select a template, it triggers the `fetchTemplateData` function. However, I also have two more selection categories, each with products in newly created rows. When I place the `fetchCategories` and `fetchProducts` code after creating rows, it clears the selections from the template. But if I move the fetch above the templateData.forEach(function(data) {...}) block, then the template selections working, but I lose the ability to select categories and products.

Added explain photo:

[image]

I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem.
I need just in selection have all categories with products, but already selected what inside in template.

```
fetchCategories($('select[name="product_category"]'));
                fetchProducts($('select.form-select'));
```

Full javascript code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function storeOriginalSellPrice(row, originalSellPrice) {
        row.data('original-sell-price', originalSellPrice);
    }

    function fetchCategories(categoryDropdown) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "fetch_categories.php",
            success: function(response) {
                categoryDropdown.html(response);
                fetchProducts(categoryDropdown);
            }
        });
    }

    function fetchProducts(categoryDropdown) {
        var category = categoryDropdown.val();
        var productDropdown = categoryDropdown.closest('tr').find('select.form-select');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetch_products.php",
            data: { category: category },
            success: function(response) {
                productDropdown.html(response);
                productDropdown.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }

    function fetchTemplateData(templateName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_template_data.php",
            data: { template_name: templateName },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);              
                var templateData = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#proposal-table tbody').empty();             
                templateData.forEach(function(data) {
                    var newRow = '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select name="product_category" class="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">' +
                        '<option value="' + data.product_category + '" selected>' + data.product_category + '</option>' +
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select class="form-select border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">' +
                        '<option value="' + data.product_name + '" selected>' + data.product_name + '</option>' +
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="quantity-input rounded w-16 text-center" value="' + data.product_quantity + '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-16 text-center sell-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-without-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-with-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="discount-input rounded w-24 text-center" value="' + data.product_discount + '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="buy-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center b2b-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center special-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center product-power-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-4 py-2 text-center">' +
                        '<button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded delete-row-btn py-1 px-3 rounded">-</button>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                    $('#proposal-table tbody').append(newRow);
                    
                });
                fetchCategories($('select[name="product_category"]'));
                fetchProducts($('select.form-select'));
            }
        });
    }

    function updateProductInfo(selectedOption) {
        var row = selectedOption.closest('tr');
        var sellPrice = parseFloat(selectedOption.data('sell-price'));
        storeOriginalSellPrice(row, sellPrice);
        row.find('.product-power-input').val(selectedOption.data('product-power'));
        row.find('.buy-price-input').val(selectedOption.data('buy-price'));
        row.find('.b2b-price-input').val(selectedOption.data('b2b-price'));
        row.find('.special-price-input').val(selectedOption.data('special-price'));
        row.find('.sell-price-input').val(sellPrice);
        updateTotals(row);
    }

    function updateTotals(row) {
        var quantity = parseInt(row.find('.quantity-input').val()) || 0;
        var sellPrice = parseFloat(row.find('.sell-price-input').val()) || 0;
        var discount = parseFloat(row.find('.discount-input').val()) || 0;
        var originalSellPrice = parseFloat(row.data('original-sell-price'));
        var discountedPrice = originalSellPrice - discount;
        var totalPriceWithoutTax = quantity * discountedPrice;
        var totalPriceWithTax = totalPriceWithoutTax * 1.21;
        row.find('.total-price-without-tax-input').val(totalPriceWithoutTax.toFixed(2));
        row.find('.total-price-with-tax-input').val(totalPriceWithTax.toFixed(2));
        row.find('.sell-price-input').val(discountedPrice.toFixed(2));
        updateTotalCalculations();
    }

    $(document).on('input', '.quantity-input, .discount-input', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        updateTotals(row);
    });

    $(document).on("change", "select.form-select", function() {
        updateProductInfo($(this).find('option:selected'));
    });

    $(document).on("change", "select[name='product_category']", function() {
        fetchProducts($(this));
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".delete-row-btn", function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        updateTotalCalculations();
    });

    $("select[name='product_category']").each(function() {
        fetchCategories($(this));
    });
    updateTotalCalculations();

    $(".add-row-btn").click(function() {
        var newRow = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<select name="product_category" class="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">' +
            '<option disabled selected><?php echo $lang['products']['category_filter']; ?></option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<select class="form-select border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full" disabled>' +
            '<option disabled selected><?php echo $lang['products']['select_product']; ?></option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="quantity-input rounded w-16 text-center"></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-16 text-center sell-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-without-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-with-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="discount-input rounded w-24 text-center"></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="buy-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center b2b-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center special-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center product-power-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-4 py-2 text-center">' +
            '<button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded delete-row-btn py-1 px-3 rounded">-</button>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        var newRowElement = $(newRow);
        $("#proposal-table tbody").append(newRowElement);
        var categoryDropdown = newRowElement.find('select[name="product_category"]');
        fetchCategories(categoryDropdown);
        var selectedTemplate = $("#template-dropdown").val();
        if (selectedTemplate !== '') {
            fetchTemplateData(selectedTemplate);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("change", "#template-dropdown", function() {
        var selectedTemplate = $(this).val();
        if (selectedTemplate !== '') {
            fetchTemplateData(selectedTemplate);
        }
    });

    // Update total calculations function
    function updateTotalCalculations() {
        var totalWithoutTax = 0;
        var totalWithTax = 0;
        var totalTax = 0;
        var totalDiscount = 0;
        var totalPower = 0;
        var support = 0;

        $('#proposal-table tbody tr').each(function() {
            var totalPriceWithoutTax = parseFloat($(this).find('.total-price-without-tax-input').val()) || 0;
            var totalPriceWithTax = parseFloat($(this).find('.total-price-with-tax-input').val()) || 0;
            var discount = parseFloat($(this).find('.discount-input').val()) || 0;
            var power = parseFloat($(this).find('.product-power-input').val()) || 0;
            var quantity = parseFloat($(this).find('.quantity-input').val()) || 0;
            totalWithoutTax += totalPriceWithoutTax;
            totalWithTax += totalPriceWithTax;
            totalTax += totalPriceWithTax - totalPriceWithoutTax;
            totalDiscount += discount * quantity;
            totalPower += power * quantity / 1000;
        });
        support = (totalPower <= 10) ? totalPower * 323 : (10 * 323);
        $('.support').val(support.toFixed(2));
        var priceWithSupport = totalWithTax - support;
        $('.fullsupport').val(priceWithSupport.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-price-without-tax').val(totalWithoutTax.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-price-with-tax').val(totalWithTax.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-tax').val(totalTax.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-discount').val(totalDiscount.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-discount-percentage').val(((totalDiscount / (totalDiscount + totalWithTax)) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        $('.total-power').val(totalPower.toFixed(2));
    }
});

    </script>
```

Comment: You're calling `fetchProducts()` in both `fetchTemplateData()` and `fetchCategories()`. One of them will overwrite what the other has done.

Comment: i need both fetch because products depend on the category to show the products of that category. any idea how to fix that?